# c# mvc 3, action overloading?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, overloading

I have been trying to overload my index method.

Here are my index methods:

```
[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult IndexDefault()
{
}

[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult IndexWithEvent(string eventName)
{
}

[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult IndexWithEventAndLanguage(string eventName, string language)
{
}
```

This keeps casting:

The current request for action 'Index' on controller type 'CoreController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult IndexDefault() on type ManageMvc.Controllers.CoreController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult IndexWithEvent(System.String) on type ManageMvc.Controllers.CoreController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult IndexWithEventAndLanguage(System.String, System.String) on type ManageMvc.Controllers.CoreController

Is it not possible to overload the index action with 3 different GET methods?

Also, if it is possible, what would be the correct route? I have this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "IndexRoute", // Route name
                "{eventName}/{language}/Core/{action}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Core", action = "Index", eventName = UrlParameter.Optional, language = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The url would look like:

localhost/Core/Index

localhost/event_name/Core/Index

localhost/event_name/language/Core/Index

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Overloading like that isn't going to work.

Your best option is to use default values and then making the route values optional (like you already have them):

```
public ActionResult Index(string eventName = null, string language = null)
{
}
```

I'm not sure you're going to get the route to look the way you want with a single route definition though. You're probably going to have to define three different routes and map each back to your single Action method.

Comment: @Patrick - Because ASP.NET MVC can't decide which of your overloads to use based on the way you defined the route (it's not smart enough to call different overloads based on which parameters are passed in the URL).

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks. I changed it around to the way you suggested and it's working.